# Is it possible to do VBA development on MS Word for Mac? E.g. Insert UserForm

Tags: vba, macos

Title says it all really.  I am using V16.78.3 using a Microsoft 365 subscription. Although I can go into Visual Basic mode, there doesn't seem to be a Toolbox window and the Insert options are severely constrained (**Module** or **Class Module**). I'm probably being dumb, but I can't find any documentation anywhere that says VBA is unavailable on Mac, which I would have expected to be shouted from the hillsides. And it is available to a *limited* extent, as I say.

---

I have finally got it kind-of working, by manually adding the following code to my module:

```
Sub Main()

Dim CoreInfo As Object

Set CoreInfo = ActiveDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

With CoreInfo
    .Properties("Caption") = "Create New Thing"
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Height") = 270
End With

End Sub
```

When I Run this, the toolbox appears and I am able to add widgets to the form. However, these don't seem to be stored anywhere in my code? Furthermore, each time I run it, I get a new Form added to the list of forms in my project. Presumably I'm meant to delete the form at runtime??

Sorry for my ignorance. I may just close this question, since it seems to have grown far beyond its original scope.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac

Comment: Yes, it is! Do you have any experience in VBA on Windows OS? It is very similar. `Toolbox` automatically appears when you try adding controls to a user form. Then, what do you mean by "Insert options are severely constrained"? Are these options disabled?

Comment: I have some experience from a couple of years ago. I wanted to create a macro with a userform. Looking at tutorials they suggested that the first step was to right click the insert menu and UserForm should be one of the options, but all I see is Module or Class Module.

Comment: My Insert menu has Procedure, Module, Class Module, File ... this is for VBA 7.1 2012, Word 16.78.3, Sonoma 14.0

Comment: @user10186832 - that's very similar to what I've got. No doubt it's context sensitive, but I've yet to find the contact which enables the 'Insert UserForm' option. It's a bit like tapping a wall to find the secret panel - very frustrating.

Comment: I'm going to give up and try and find a larger code example. Maybe the process will become clearer at that point.

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate your input, but I found this link using google. However, it does not answer my essential question, of how to enable the Insert/Userform option.

Comment: @FaneDuru https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/userform-does-not-appear-as-an-option-in-excel-vba/dd51b1a6-3090-4e77-a0da-f19872b132e0

Comment: [Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/mac-os-userform-alternative/m-p/2279567) is a link to a Microsoft site which says that MS have removed user forms from Excel for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this link:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/user-form-in-vba-for-excel-in-office-365-for-mac/ae62c9fe-0873-49a0-8ba7-d784ff19f41e

I suspect that this option is simply not available on Mac. Although the post is dated 2019, the symptoms exactly match my experience.